# rake db:migrate alter table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I wanted to change the name of a table I creted with rake db:migrate from financialss to financials. I created a file in my migrate directory called changeme.rb that looks like this.

```
 class CreateFinancials < ActiveRecord::Migration
        def self.up
             rename_table :financials, :financialss
        end

        def self.down
              rename_table :financialss, :financials
        end
   end
```

I tried to run the following:

rake db:migrate:up changeme.rb

and got the following error:

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate:changeme.rb'

All help appreciated

Comment: Why not just create a normal migration?

Comment: not sure what you mean? I have the orginal migration I used to create the table, would I edit that?

Comment: Use `rails g migration RenameFinancialsTable`, modify that file to look like this one, and then run `rake db:migrate`.  A custom named file as you have it isn't supported by ActiveRecord::Migration

Comment: PinnyM, Thanks worked beautifully. Please make it an official answer so that I can give you full credit for it.

Comment: You can accept Eduardo's answer, as it is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use the rails generator

```
rails g migration MigrationName
```

The rails do not understand when you come out of the convention. So try to use the default generator.